# scale background image

Tags: html, css, web, background-image

I would like to scale up and down a background image in my page. I've tried multiple things but nothing quite seems to work the way I want. :(  The url of my page is http://quaaoutlodge.com/drupal-7.14/ and for each link, there's a different background image. I know the size and quality of the images will need to be optimized but I first want to figure out the techincal part of it. If someone please coudl assist in getting this going?

Thank you very much!
Ron

Comment: Do you mean when you resize the window?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Same background image on every page

If you want a background-image that resizes and fills the entire window space, no matter what the size, then use this CSS,

```
html { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

### Different background image on every page

In case you want a different background image for each page,

**HTML**

```
<div id="bg">
    <img src="<?=$imgsrc;?>" alt="">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bg {
    position:fixed; 
    top:-50%; 
    left:-50%; 
    width:200%; 
    height:200%;
}

#bg img {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    right:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    margin:auto; 
    min-width:50%;
    min-height:50%;
}
```

Source: [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/)

Comment: But I want a different image for each page

Comment: Then use a img tag and through php pass the image source to it.

Comment: I actually ended up, including the html {} definition into my html inline - works really well :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Antoher way to achieve this can be found at MDN:

```
.foo {
  background-image: url(bg-image.png);

  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Safari 3.0 */
     -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Gecko 1.9.2 (Firefox 3.6) */
       -o-background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Opera 9.5 */
          background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4.0) and other CSS3-compliant browsers */

  -moz-border-image: url(bg-image.png) 0;    /* Gecko 1.9.1 (Firefox 3.5) */
}
```

IE Fallback:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='path_relative_to_the_HTML_file', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 1):

Nice to see html background-image being used well. Because some developers depend on  trailing edge css to maintain backwards compatibility, many quirks exist for otherwise `css3` compatible browsers. Like `background:cover` in older Safari versions (<4.05), which does not work. In this case we can use the older `css3` vendor fallback as shown

```
html { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-backgound-size:100% 100%; /* early css3 implementation */
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
}
```

And, if by chance you want different background images for different pages in pure css, lets go with

```
html#bg1 {backrgound-image:url(images/bg1.jpg);}
html#bg2 {background-image:url(images/bg2.jpg);}
```

But, if you cannot give your `<html>` tag an `id` or `class` you may have to resort to some `javascript`. You can then use a different background image for each page on the `<html>` element, which is just what is needed. This seems to work fine on the `html` tag. Some browsers ignore the `css` for `background-image` when used on `html`. The `body` tag is less temperamental. This may be a better fix than the php-based method. For example:

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.backgroundImage='url(images/bg3.jpg)';
</script>
```

The html css for background-size would continue to apply and would cover correctly across various browser versions. Note however, that older Safari will throw an error on `javascript` which uses an empty url, say to clear the background image, e.g.

```
<script> /*Causes Error Safari 4*/
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.backgroundImage='url()';
</script>
```

The error will normally halt `javascript` execution with no clue as to the cause. Instead we need to use `style.backgroundImage='none';`

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query in your CSS to specify a background image for different screen sizes:

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
background-image:url('rightsizebackground.jpg');
}
```

Comment: But I want to load a different image for each page... is there a way to pass variables from html(php) through to css?