# CSS Positioning in Relative DIV

Tags: css, position

How can I make it so the Div "PSR-racing-3-slice-17_" in the footer is always 50 px right of the slider div?

If I absolutely positioned then it warps downsize the browser.

Here's the [Page](http://psr.mediameans.de).

Comment: Not sure what you're looking to do. Can you give us more detail in the question?

Comment: the image in den div of slice 17 next to the slider div on the right side

Comment: Please include relevant code here, rather than just linking to your site. See [Something on my website doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#PSR-racing-3-slice-17_ {
    width: 1115px;
    height: 132px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

#PSR-racing-3-slice-17_ img {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -90px;
}
```

Change `margin-top` to whatever you feel is right.

Comment: it works better but if i resize the browser it moves...

Comment: thanks, the same with the header and footer background always when i resize the browser it moves

Comment: Any idea how i can make that the header and the footer background don´t move when i resize the browser window ?

Comment: See if this answer helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386883/scale-background-image/11386928#11386928.

Comment: the   background-size: cover doesn´t works the width is 100% of the image

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13633/discussion-between-tom-means-and-abhshkdz)